# Broadcast receiver is working on emulator and phone, but not tablet

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, multiple-instances

My android app contains activity that is launched multiple times to move in tree-like structure. To close all activities of this structure i have declared a **Broadcast receiver** to wait for intent and finish activity when need. Every instance of this activity starts its own receiver with the same action name.

All aspects of this app are working on emulator API20 and Sony Xperia S with 4.1.2 version.
On Manta MID709 tablet (same android version as xperia), receiver works only when particular activity is on top(running and visible). So it closes one instance of this activity or none if i launch something new.

The code to declare broadcast receiver (outside onCreate, but inside Activity):

```
public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.application.STOP")) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Intent Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

        }
    }
};
```

The code to activate closing:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent();
        intent2.setAction("com.application.STOP");
        sendBroadcast(intent2);
```

On emulator and xperia i end with three(three instances were running) "Intent Received" toasts and app closes. On tablet there is sometimes one "Intent received" toast or none.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty simple and the code was 100% good. I had checked in my tablet in developer options  to not keep activities. In other words, abort every activity that is not present. It was killing my Broadcast receivers. Hope that this answer will help someone :)